# How to find maximum(or minimum) in any subarray(of any size) in a given array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

We are given an array and some queries. Each query contains two numbers `i` and `j`. We need to find the maximum(or minimum) element in the subarray starting from index `i` and ending at index `j` in the given array.

For Eg.

```
arr = [2 , 3 , 5,  8 , 4 , 9]
```

and

```
query 1: (2 , 4)
```

The subarray corresponding to this query will be `[5 , 8 , 4]`. So, the maximum will be `8`.

**Note:** Number of queries is about 10^5 and there are about 10^6 elements in the array. Also the time limit for the execution of the program is 1s . So, I guess a solution is needed which has complexity of O(log n) or less per query, where n is the number of elements in the array.

Comment: **Easy way:** linearly iterate from `i` to `j` and find maximum or minimum. **Better way:** build an [RSQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). It all depends on the total number of items in array, number and complexity of queries.

Comment: Thanks @yeldar . There will about 10^6 elements in the array and near about 10^5 queries. And the program should give result within 1 s. So I don't think that easy way will prove to be useful. It would be really helpful, if you please elaborate the second way.

Comment: As far as I remember from my ACM experience, 10^6 sounds exactly like RSQ limitations. Just find for sum segment tree, there should be a solution in the Internet. What language are you using?

Comment: @yeldar I use C++

Comment: Have a look at this ... [RMQ topcoder tutorial](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a homework-type question and there is no evidence that the asker has done any work.

Comment: You could sort the queries by start/end, which should take just a few milliseconds. Then, do a single pass through the array. You'll need a stack to hold intermediate results in the case of overlapping queries, which in the worst case would require O(number of queries) extra space.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate Yeldar's RSQ idea, and assuming you only need to find maxima (otherwise, repeat this structure for minima as well):
-You already have the value for each entry.  Now break your array into pairs, and store the maximum value of each pair.  (So in your example you'd get 3,8,9).  Then break those into pairs (of 4 original entries) and store the maximum of that (so 8,9; the odd one out stays by itself).  Repeat until you're down to a single pair, giving you the maximum of the entire array.  Thus, you have multiple levels of a tree, each corresponding to a subarray.

-Now, you can use this tree to find each maximum more efficiently: If you need to find the maximum from i to j, find the smallest subarray in the tree that entirely contains the range from i to j.  Now you can see (from your tree) the maximum of that subarray, so trace it down (since the subarray each higher level is made up of the subarrays of two lower levels) until you get something either entirely contained in the range from i to j, or entirely disjoint.  As you trace, keep track of the maximum of each path you don't take.

If it's entirely contained, you have your answer (the maximum of that range).  If it's entirely disjoint, then it's not your answer (it comes from something not in the range), so take the highest maximum from the path you didn't take and repeat the process (adding in any new untaken paths), until your maximum does end up being from a subarray entirely contained in the range.

Comment: Hey thanks for explanation. Can you please give me some link where I can find the code related to that because whenever I search RSQ on Google it gives me some weird things.

Comment: @GauravJha: You've already been given a link to a [great article on TopCoder](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/). Read the section "A <O(N), O(sqrt(N))> solution". There is no code in that section, but the explanation is clear and you should be able to write the code yourself. If you can't, post a question with the partial code that you've written and explain the difficulty you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Can use STL:max_element

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{2,3,5,8,4,9};
    int initial , end;
    cin>>initial>>end;
    cout <<*(std::max_element(v.begin()+initial,v.begin()+end));
    return 0;

}
```

other way will only work in c++17

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3de476681d9e1374

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    decltype(auto) v = std::experimental::make_array(2,3,5,8,4,9);
    int initial=2,end=4;
    cout <<*(std::max_element(v.begin()+initial,v.begin()+end));
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It says that the function max_element has complexity linear in number of elements compared and if you will see my edit then you will find that it will be timeout. By the way thanks I learned a function which is completely new to me.

Comment: Can you please share the sample Input or the forum where you are trying this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the maximum and minimum for the initial input by iterating through all the elements and for the next input if i and j contains the previous input then you can save time by using the previous result.

Comment: Will that stand the worst case?

Comment: The worst case would be when there is no overlap of the index. Then this method will be equivalent to passing through all the elements once to find max and min. In the average case this method will be efficient as compared to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to store the array as a balanced search tree that stores the minimum under every node, such that every index is mapped to its value.

Then you can split by j, split by i (the balanced tree maintains the current nodes subtrees minimums), and return the root min. Then join back the (up to) 3 trees you got.

The construction is O(n log n) and the query is O(log n) [since split & join are done in O(log n)]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
counter = i-1
max = MIN_INTEGER
min = MAX_INTEGER
while counter < j:
  if arr[counter] > max:
    max = arr[counter]
  if arr[counter] < min:
    min = arr[counter]
  counter++
return max,min
```

Edit:

Alternatively, insert it into a maxheap and minheap (O(n)), and thereafter the queries would all be O(1).

Comment: I think this solution will not help as per the time constraints.

Comment: @GauravJha Didn't see your edits. I edited accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: May be I sound dumb but I didn't get what to insert into maxheap or minheap(is it the complete array). If you are talking about inserting the whole array in minheap or maxheap then how will we get the result of query in O(1). By the way, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, actually I do realize that that would still take O(n) time unless you can pre-process the array/process one time then do many queries. Additionally, that would mean the worst case might still be O(nlogn). Assuming you want find the max of a sub array that is only [2] (where 2 is the smallest in the whole array), then you would end up popping the whole tree. Sorry, seems like I can't provide a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use C++ STL (this is a modification of previously stated solution. We need to add +1 at the end. Because it takes index in the range [start, end). Hope this helps. Try this problem for better understanding. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/service-lane/problem

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> arr{2,3,5,8,4,9};
    int i; // start index
    int j; // end index
    cin >> i >> j;
    cout << *max_element(arr.begin()+i, arr.begin()+j+1);

    return 0;
}
```